# scala regex.. single pattern to match when one or multiple records are present

Tags: scala

I need a scala solution, that is a single pattern that will match my first record entry that spans multiple lines among multiple records. The record will always start with the word RECORD.

Scenario1

```
==================================================
RECORD-1

        "FOO BAR"

        "ID-100"

         "TOY"

==================================================
```

Scenario2

```
==================================================
RECORD-1

        "FOO BAR"

        "ID-100"

         "TOY"

RECORD-2

        "X BAR"

        "ID-200"

         "DOLL"

RECORD-3

        "Y BAR"

        "ID-400"

         "STATUE"

==================================================
```

In both the scenarios, I need the first record, "FOO BAR" to be extracted using scala code. REPL solutions are more welcome.

Comment: any attempt from your side ?

Comment: So there are one or more RECORDs in a file and you just want the first one?

Comment: @Flint, I was having below perl code that works.. wanted to simulate the same in scala echo -e "Record ...\nRecord ...\nRecord ..." | perl -ne ' BEGIN {$/=""} { $_=~s/Record(.+?)(<?Record)(.*)/Record\1/mosg; print }'
echo -e "Record ..." | perl -ne ' BEGIN {$/=""} { $_=~s/Record(.+?)(<?Record)(.*)/Record\1/mosg; print }'

Comment: @iwvh.. yes you are right. the RECORD will always start at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a simple capture of everything until the 2nd record.

```
scala> val firstRec = io.Source.fromFile("records.txt").getLines.takeWhile(_ != "RECORD-2")
firstRec: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

From there you can trim the record of unwanted parts (headers, blank lines, whatever).

Comment: thanks for the solution... adding some complexity to the original question. Assume that I have 10 records and have 3 duplicates on "FOO BAR". The duplicates are appearing consecutively, say 6th, 7th, and 8th record. In that case, can I extract the 6th RECORD alone?. That is.. the first record among the "FOO BAR" duplicates.

Comment: I think for that scenario it might be easiest to read all the records and pack them in a data format that allows for easy processing (filtering, duplicate detection, etc.).

Comment: I'm struggling.. How do I put into a data format?. could you please show a solution.

Comment: 1st - I don't know the exact constraints of your record format. For example: the scenarios you've given has many blank lines. Is that always the case? etc. 2nd - This is actually a new question and deserves to be presented in a new post.  That way more people will see it and you're likely to get better answers.